# Getting duplicates in list even though not in should be working correctly in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop

Just trying to create a list of all unique names using "not in" but duplicates are still showing up in the results. At the moment, I'm just using data from an excel spreadsheet. Perhaps there is something wrong with the data.

```
  List = Subclasses.split(',')

  for item in List:
      if item not in UniqueSubClasses:
          UniqueSubClasses.append(item)
          NewUniqueSubClasses = [item.strip() for item in UniqueSubClasses]
```

When I go to print the results, theres a few duplicates. What makes me question the data is the first few results, where there are extra characters. I've tried clearing all formatting of the data and that didn't seem to work. But then there are just duplicate names as well.

```
['Arcana Cleric', 'Arcane Trickster Rogue', 'Eldritch Knight Fighter', 'Nature Cleric', 'Arcane Archer Fighter', 'Arcane Trickster Rogue', 'Eldritch Knight Fighter', 'Divine Soul Sorcerer', 'Arcana\xa0Cleric', 'Arcane Trickster\xa0Rogue', 'Celestial\xa0Warlock', 'Divine Soul\xa0Sorcerer', 'Eldritch Knight\xa0Fighter', 'Light\xa0Cleric', 'Swarmkeeper\xa0Ranger', 'Nature\xa0Cleric', 'Nature\xa0Cleric', 'Aberrant Mind\xa0Sorcerer', 'Arcana Cleric', 'Illusion\xa0Wizard', 'Arcane Archer\xa0Fighter', 'Nature Cleric', 'Divine Soul\xa0Sorcerer', 'Celestial\xa0Warlock', 'Chronurgy  Wizard', 'Graviturgy Wizard', 'Grave Cleric', 'Undying Warlock', 'Divine Soul Sorcerer', 'Arcane Trickster Rogue', 'Arcane Trickster\xa0Rogue', 'Clockwork Soul\xa0Sorcerer', 'Watchers\xa0Paladin', 'Conquest Paladin', 'Vengeance Paladin', 'Life Cleric', 'Fiend Warlock', 'Genie Warlock', 'Light Cleric', 'Wildfire Druid', 'Fey Wanderer Ranger', 'Trickery Cleric', 'Crown Paladin', 'Glamour Bard', 'Knowledge Cleric', 'Order Cleric', 'Crown Paladin', 'Fathomless Warlock', 'Celestial Warlock', 'Watchers Paladin', 'Gloom Stalker Ranger', 'Great Old One Warlock', 'War Cleric', 'Ancients Paladin', 'Archfey Warlock', 'Swarmkeeper Ranger', 'Twilight Cleric', 'Death Cleric', 'Genie Warlock', 'Tempest Cleric', 'Chronurgy Wizard', 'Glory Paladin', 'Alchemist Artificer', 'Oathbreaker Paladin', 'Battle Smith Artificer', 'Peace Cleric', 'Vengeance Paladin', 'Forge Cleric', 'Oathbreaker Paladin', 'Armorer Artificer', 'Graviturgy Wizard', 'Clockwork Soul Sorcerer', 'Devotion Paladin', 'Horizon Walker Ranger', 'Monster Slayer Ranger', 'Devotion 
Paladin', 'Redemption Paladin', 'Forge Cleric', 'Artillerist Artificer', 'Battle Smith Artificer', 'Hexblade Warlock', 'War Cleric', 'Archfey Warlock', 'Totem Warrior Barbarian', 'Hexblade Warlock', 'Clockwork Soul Sorcerer', 'Moon Druid', 'Ancestral Guardian Barbarian', 'Eldritch Knighter Fighter', 'Land (Forest) Druid', 'Totem Warrior Barbarian', 'Spores Druid', 'Land (Desert) Druid', 'Aberrant Mind 
Sorcerer', 'Land (Swamp) Druid', 'Shadow Sorcerer', 'Great Old One\xa0Warlock', 'Celestial Warlock', 'Fathomless Warlock', 'Conquest Paladin', 'Land (Arctic) Druid', 'Land (Grassland) Druid', 'Land (Coast) Druid', 'Land (Grassland) Druid', 'Land (Forest) Druid', 'Land (Mountain) Druid', 'Land (Underdark) Druid', 'Genie Warlock', 'Artillerist Artificer', 'Glory Paladin', 'Death Cleric', 'Land (Coast) Druid', 'Tempest Cleric', 'Monster Slayer Ranger', 'Watchers Paladin', 'Fey Wanderer Ranger', 'Trickery Cleric', 'Armorer Artificer']
```

Anyway, thanks in advance. I would really appreciate any help :)

Comment: What is `UniqueSubClasses`, what are the "results" that you print, what is `NewUniqueSubClasses` and why do you recreate it.

Comment: Well NewUniqueSubClasses was just a dup of UniqueSubClasses but everything is stripped. I just didn't know how to strip them all once they were in the list.

Answer (score 0):

maybe:

```
List = Subclasses.split(',')

for item in List:
    if item.strip() not in UniqueSubClasses:
        UniqueSubClasses.append(item.strip())
        NewUniqueSubClasses = [item for item in UniqueSubClasses]
```

Comment: Ahhh I see the problem now, that makes a lot of sense. I was seeing if the non stripped version was in the list. Thanks a lot for your help :)